# How do I open a file with a specific application rather than its default application?

Tags: vb.net, process.start

I am trying to open files using a specified executable; just like as if you were to right mouse click on a file then scroll to "Open with"

---

[image]

---

I tried what [kaymaf said](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8bb2c6d7-aa79-4a47-a4d8-6dea39f82a42/open-a-file-with-specific-program?forum=vbgeneral) and reviewed the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0), but I cannot seem to get this to work.

```
Dim FI As New FileInfo(GetFileNameFromListViewItem(ListViewCollection.SelectedItems(0)))
Dim GetExif As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\Users\*username*\Downloads\exiftool.exe", FI.FullName)
```

This just ends up open the executable and rather than opening the file with the executable.

Comment: Does exiftool.exe accept a filename argument?  What happens if you call the exact same command via the command prompt with the filename argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would like to open a file with your program using the Windows context menu; and do you want to get an entry in that menu? If that is not correct, the answer can be deleted.

I found [this in a German forum](https://www.vb-paradise.de/index.php/Thread/133572-Windows-Contextmen%C3%BC/?postID=1153840#post1153840), and they refer to [this](http://www.ookii.org/Blog/opening_files_via_idroptarget_in_net) site:

This is the translated text:

One possibility would be that you register your file extension and your program in the system to open this file extension. As soon as the system knows everything, you only need to right-click on the file(s) and in the context menu, in addition to the standard entries, another menu item for opening these files is displayed. If you select this menu item, your program will start automatically if it has not yet started, and you can read out / determine the path to this file or several files in your program and process it accordingly. How it all works is described here: ookii.org/Blog/opening_files_via_idroptarget_in_net

On this page there is also a sample for download (start text files with your own program via an additional entry in the context menu / display paths to the files). It is not a VB, but it should be translatable without any problems. Corresponding information on the page and the comments should be observed.

Comment: Yes, perfect! Thank you so much!